# CSS3 Menu Shows Up Wrong (CSS3/HTML5)

Tags: html, css

I've been working on a CSS3 menu, it's pretty much finished.. But, there is a little problem, the main `li`'s are not really positioned good. If anyone could help me? I've got my site online and you could maybe inspect element? I think placing my code here would just take to much space etc..

Link: http://weveloped.com/

As you can see, the first `li` is placed horizontally, but the second one+ are placed vertically. How can I make sure all the `li`'s are placed horizontally? It's probably something with the display's in the CSS code, but I can't seem to find the problem.

HTML CODE:

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: rgba(24, 24, 24, 1);
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 400ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 400ms ease;
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}
header ul,
header li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
header.sticky {
  height: 50px;
  /*background-color: rgba(24,24,24,0.6);*/
}
header nav {
  text-align: right;
}
header nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
header nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 85px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  line-height: 85px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
}
header nav li:hover > a {
  color: #A80000;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 400ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 400ms ease;
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}
header nav li section.row {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease;
  transition: all 200ms ease;
}
header nav li section.row ul li {
  display: block;
}
header nav li section.row ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0px 17px 0px 17px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  color: #555;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #333941;
}
header nav li section.row ul li a:hover {
  color: #A80000;
}
header nav li section.row ul li:last-child a {
  border: none;
}
header nav li section.row ul li.title a {
  color: #222;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-top: 12px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  border: none;
}
header nav li:hover > section.row {
  overflow: visible;
  max-width: 960px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <li><a href="#">Homepage</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
      <section class="row">
        <section class="three columns">
          <ul>
            <li class="title"><a href="#">Website Design</a>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Website Structure Design</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Mobile Website Design</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Parallax/Responsive Design</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Bespoke Design</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </section>
        <section class="three columns">
          <ul>
            <li class="title"><a href="#">CManagement Systems</a>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">WordPress</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Drupal</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Joomla</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Bespoke CMS</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </section>
        <section class="three columns">
          <ul>
            <li class="title"><a href="#">Website Development</a>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">CManagement System</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">WebApp Development</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">eCommerce Development</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Bespoke Development</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </section>
        <section class="three columns">
          <ul>
            <li class="title"><a href="#">Our Work</a>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Reviews</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Give a Review</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </section>
      </section>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to read up on the `section` element. Every `section` element you have should be a `div`or `span`

Comment: You should also add the code in your question. Linking to an external website means the question will be of no use to anybody viewing this once the problem is fixed. You can use jsfiddle or similar if you are unable to extract a small enough portion of code to put directly in the question.

Comment: @MichaelLawton I'll add the code to the post, by the way, `section` is just a replacement for `div` in HTML5.

Comment: Sorry but that's incorrect - read this article http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/

Comment: your markup has no header tag (although using one would be wrong as well). Either wrap your `<nav>` in a class called `header` and hen alter `header` in your css to `.header`, or remove this `header` from your css altogether. Otherwise, It's an issue that you're not using `display:inline-block` somewhere in your markup.

Comment: @jbutler483 There's a header tag in my mark up, just didn't send all the code. Also, I'm using `inline-block` for the first level `li`'s, for the second level's I'm using `block`.

Comment: @MichaelLawton Oh, allright.. I'll take a look at that.

Comment: @Peurr: you may want to add that header tag in - that way your snippet would 'work' at replicating the issue. I for one do not like visiting external sites to debug.

Comment: @jbutler483 The code snipet doesn't look good now either, not the way it's presented at my site. I might just find myself the problem, just some research. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Your problem is that submenu (child of `li`) needs to be absolutely positioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `section` element in the Services `li`: it wants to be as wide as the `li`'s parent, so it pushes everything down. Give that `section` `position: absolute;` and you should be golden.